# pyqt: Fixed Position

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

How can I give a widget a fixed position? Like so I can "attach"/put it at the bottom of the window and it will always be there; even when the window is expanded. I couldn't find anything useful on how to do it and, I suppose obviously, none of the obvious things work (`resize()`, `setGeometry()`, etc.). Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "fixed position" you mean a position relative to one of the window edges.  That's what your second sentence implies.  So that's the question I will answer.

Use a layout manager with stretches and spacings.  Here's a simple example to attach a widget "w" to the bottom of a window "win".  This code typically gets called by (or goes inside) your window's constructor.

```
lay = QVBoxLayout(win)
lay.addStretch(1)
lay.addWidget(w)
```

The BoxLayout makes "w" stick to the bottom of the window and stay in that position as the window is resized.

Answer (score -1):

you must reimplement the parent windows resizeEvent function, here is the code to make a widget "attached" to the bottom of the window:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    #widget.move(x, y)
    self.bottom_widget.move(0, self.height() - self.bottom_widget.height())
    #if you want the widgets width equal to window width:
    self.bottom_widget.setWidth(self.width())
```

whenever the window is resized, this function will be called and it will move the widget to the bottom of the window. this is an absolute positioning approach, but you can always use QSpacerItem to push your widget to the bottom.